# respect 3 columns in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a page with Bootstrap. The idea is create 3 columns on the left show star (links), in center a word "Infilmtrats" in Catalan, and right other stars (other links)

But it deforms both computer, mobile and tablet. I would like to look good in the 3 devices...

Mobile devices in the 2nd column is not centered , and third jumps to the next line ( after the word " infilmtrats " ) .

You know some idea? I'm trying to "float" but no way , I spend my code.

Thank you very much .

CURRENT. http://www.infilmtrats.com/interrogatorios/

YES, SHOULD BE http://oi60.tinypic.com/28b8mu0.jpg

```
<div class="row"> 
<div class="pull-left"><br/><br/><br/> 
    <p><img src="start.gif" alt="estrella" width="52" height="47" class="size-full wp-image-302" /></p> 
</div> 
<div class="centered" style="text-align: center;"> 
    <h1 style="color: #ffffff;">I<br /> N<br /> T<br /> E<br /> R<br /> R<br /> O<br /> G<br /> A<br /> T<br /> O<br /> R<br /> I<br /> O<br /> S<br /> </h1> </div> 
<div class="pull-right"> 
    <p><img src="start.gif" alt="estrella" width="52" height="47" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-302" /></p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the Bootstrap column classes? (i.e. `col-sm-4`?)

Comment: You need to use the Bootstrap Grid System (Main reason to use Bootstrap). Read the documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: you are using the bootstrap framework wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your column divs. Like this:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="pull-left"> ... <div>
<div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="centered"> ... <div>
<div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="pull-right"> ... <div>
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: in desktop working, but in mobile device no, can you test here: http://www.infilmtrats.com/interrogatorios/  the 3 colums jump to the next line , and the word " infilmtrats " is affected . thanks you very much

Comment: @IvanMenethil please make an attempt to read the Bootstrap documentation on how grid columns behave: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the column classes of the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). By default there are 12 columns in the grid system. If you want 3 columns then divide 12/3 = 4 to get how wide each column should be.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        Left
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        Center
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

The various sizes that are associated with the columns (`xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`) determine at what point the columns will become full width and begin stacking.

Comment: Since OP wants to use in mobile, why not use `col-xs-4` instead?

Comment: You must have missed the point I made about the different column sizes. Besides, `col-xs-*` isn't exclusively for mobile devices. Nothing says that I cannot use `col-md-*` for one row and `col-lg-*` for the next row. The same goes for nested columns. It all depends on how and when you want your columns to collapse.

Comment: My point was, since the user wanted mobile, why start at `md`... We *know* we need the mobile version to be three columns... you are making it more confusing for the OP (and it is obvious that he does not understand bootstrap's grid system yet)

Comment: Uncalled-for-sarcasm non-withstanding, every one learns differently. You don't have to make the lesson a *mystery* for them to learn it.   Also, it's a big leap of judgement from "not knowing bootstrap" to "hand-holding going thru life" - but of course, you want to be right so you need to belittle others to feel superior.  Good grief!!!

Comment: You continue to try and "educate" me, so whom here has to be _right_? Using column classes is 98% of the answer, the other 2% is which column class to use. Five minutes going over the docs and boom! You've learned a little more about Bootstrap that will solve that last little piece and you'll have more knowledge of the framework that will benefit you in the future.